# how to set url prams when <c:redirect url=""> is used in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

In my web app I have admin.jsp page, there I can do some amin stuff, I want to restrict directly accessing it and if admin is logged-in then he is free to do admin stuff there for this case I have code :

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.admin}">                 
    <!-- Post -->
    <article class="is-post is-post-excerpt">
        <header>                                    
        h2>Welcome to Admin Area</h2>
        </header>
</article>  
</c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <c:redirect url="/context/controller?action=log-in"/>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

through above code I'm getting correct results and I see url as /context/login.jsp, but I want this line

```
/context/controller?action=log-in
```

should come in the url I used :

```
<jsp:forward page="/context/controller?action=log-in"/>
```

it shows me /context/admin.jsp, no params and a blank page, Please help me in setting `/context/controller?action=log-in` back into url so that I can get and use param.

## UPDATE

Using answer bellow in admn.jsp I have

```
<c:redirect url="/context/controller?action=log-in">
<c:param name="action" value="log-in"></c:param>
</c:redirect>
```

and for testing in login.jsp I have

```
<article class="is-post is-post-excerpt">
<header>
<h2>Login
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty param.action}">
        <c:out value="${param.action}"></c:out>                                         
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
</h2>
</header>                               
</article>
```

I'm unable to get that param and still I get `/context/login.jsp` url.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
<c:redirect url="/context/controller?action=log-in">
<c:param name="firstName" value="fred"></c:param>
</c:redirect>
```

Comment: so you are redirecting to `/context/controller` not `login.jsp`.  Ensure that your controller is passing along the request paramaters.